# Realm asObservable() emit only new items

Tags: realm, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava, and trying to use the Realm Observable feature.

When  doing this

```
realm.where(Intake.class)
            .findAllSorted("time", Sort.DESCENDING)
            .asObservable()
```

I get the full list of items, but when soemthing changes (ie item added), I get the full list again.

What is the RxJava-way to get only the new items?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently observing the query results. Because your query can contain multiple items (`findAllSorted()`), you're always observing the `RealmResults` that will emit all sorted items when there's a change (see [docs](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmResults.java#L999)).

You can do something like this:

```
realm.where(Intake.class)
    .findAllSorted("time", Sort.DESCENDING)
    .asObservable()
    .flatMapIterable(results -> results)
    .distinct();
```

This does 2 more things:

- convert your `RealmResults` to singular `Intake` instances
- only let distinct items pass through (make sure your `Intake` implements `equals()` correctly)

This does however impose some extra CPU load, because each time the query passes on a new `RealmResult`, processing is done to filter out the distinct items.

In the above example, sorting will work on the initial set of emitted `Intake` objects. However, any subsequent emitted items could be observed out of order because they are new and emitted after the initial results.

Comment: and how would you handle deleted items?

Comment: I am not familiar with Realm, but my guess is to call filter() on the Intake Observable to filter out deleted ones.